# MFMailComposersheet does not allocates in device iOS 5.1 version

Tags: iphone, ipad, xcode4

I have the following line of code,

```
 MFMailComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];

 picker.mailComposeDelegate = self;

 [picker setSubject:APP_NAME];

 [picker addAttachmentData:pdfData mimeType:@"pdf" fileName:pdfFileName];

 NSString *emailBody = @"";

 [picker setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:YES];

 [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
```

But iPad just stuck at the first line of the code.

```
MFMailComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
```

When i put the break point on the another line it does not come to the second line of code it is just stuck and does not open MailCompserSheet and it is hung.

This problem appears only on iOS version 5.1 in iPad.

So anyway have idea what to do?

Comment: Just to be sure, could you put in an NSLog after the first line to make sure it doesn't go there, and see how it goes.

Comment: @Madhu how can i put NSLog because it is not come from the first line to the second line, debugger is stop at first line. please help if you find same type of problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you might not have configured mail in your iPad.

So before initializing the class `MFMailComposeViewController`, call [MFMailComposeViewController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMailComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html)'s `+ (BOOL)canSendMail` to check whether you can be able to send mail with the device or not.

Comment: It is already configured in ipad but i delete the account and add again it will solve my Problem, Thanks for hint.